# What's the proper way to update the "published" field on a Photo using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

When I try to update the `published` field on an existing Photo object I get: `OAuthException code 1: "An unknown error has occurred."`  Here's what I'm trying:

**Upload an image:**

```
$ curl -X POST -F published=false -F "access_token=$TOKEN" -F file=@soccer.jpg https://graph.facebook.com/$ALBUM_ID/photos
```

**Grab the link and verify that the link shows up for me, but not my friends:**

```
$ curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/$PHOTO_ID?fields=link&access_token=$TOKEN"
```

**Set the published bit:**

```
$ curl -X POST -F published=true -F "access_token=$TOKEN" https://graph.facebook.com/$PHOTO_ID
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1,"fbtrace_id":"D+Z1Gs9zZat"}}%
```

According to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/#Updating) that field *is* available for updating. So is this a documentation bug or an API bug?

I'm trying to upload a bunch of pictures with `published=false` and then publish them all at the same time later by just updating the published field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's currently a bug in the platform.  [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/260614330960310)'s the bug report.